# Uploading an file into varbinary

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

how to upload a file into varbinary using ASP.NET/C# upload button.

I need the syntax to use the upload button. And how to restrict the upload of only image files?

I need things in ASP.NET using C# and MySQL database using ODBC commands.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you having problem with get the file from the web or are you having trouble storing the file in the database? Focus your question on your real problem and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Nope.! I couldn't understand how to use upload button. Else I could have started to try.

Comment: Ok, so your problem has nothing to do with varbinary? Your problem has to do with the upload button, right?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. If you follow those guide lines people will find it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to upload into your system file than database.